# jquery replace broken image with noimage icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, replace

I have a couple of images links that don't have any images yet but I know when they are available they will be named pic1 and pic2.jpg so i setup theimage src for img tag. but until the image is available I don't want the red cross for broken image to show up, so i have noimage.jpg icon that should replace the src of all broken image. I am using this and its kinda working but noimage icon replaces the broken image after a quick flash of broken image red cross. Can we prevent the quick flash that does show the red cross broken image thing completely so user only sees the noimage icon..

```
$("img").error(function () {  
 $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "noimage.gif"); });
```

Comment: is it currently wrapped in a jQuery document ready call?

Comment: Why not have the images fade in on DOM load? This _should_ possibly solve the problem of the flash because the image will be loaded and substituted by then

Comment: It is inside document.ready(){}How do you make images fade in??

Comment: Here is fast way to do it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images#answer-21858938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(function() {
    $("img").one("load", function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).each(function() {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    }).error(function () {  
        $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "noimage.gif");
    }).hide();
});
```

On document ready it will hide every image and then run the "load" method to show them, whilst also including your error handling code.

Comment: It worked. Hope it doesn't create page performance issue, does it?

Comment: The above code isn't anything heavy, so I wouldn't worry about it.  If you're talking about 1000s of images then anything you do will have a performance impact.

Comment: Incidentally, if you did like the idea of images fading in, as mentioned by JohnP, just change the .show() to .fadeIn(interval-in-ms).  That may have a performance impact though, as fading of any element takes a lot more effort than a simple show.